Bad numerical solution in a Finite Element code implementing Taylor--Hood method to solve the stationary Stokes problem
I'm implementing the stationary Stokes problem using the Taylor--Hood finite element method:
$-2\nu\Delta u+\nabla p=f$ in $\Omega$
$\nabla\cdot u=0$ in $\Omega$
$u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$
The exact solution, velocity and pressure, is:
$u=\Big(1000 {{\left( x-1\right) }^{4}} {{x}^{2}} \left( y-1\right)  {{y}^{2}} \left( 5 y-3\right)),\quad -2000 {{\left( x-1\right) }^{3}} x\, \left( 3 x-1\right)  {{\left( y-1\right) }^{2}} {{y}^{3}}\Big)$
$p={{\left( x-\frac{1}{2}\right) }^{3}} {{y}^{2}}+{{\left( 1-x\right) }^{3}} {{\left( y-\frac{1}{2}\right) }^{3}}$
In this example, $\Omega =[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $\nu=1$.
At the left, is the P2/P1 solution, and at the right the P3/P2 solution, where Pk/Pm means that the velocity and pressure belongs to the space of polynomials of degree less than k and m, respectively. The numerical solution in each row uses the same criss-cross mesh composed by triangles.
In all cases, the velocity is well approximated. And I checked that the divergence of the velocity is 0, and $\int\Omega p=0$.
The solution for P3/P2 (right) is very close to the exact solution, but the solution using P2/P1 (left) is not very good for coarse meshes. But, in both cases, the rate of convergence is what we expect.
Because is a home-made code, I'm not sure if this is what we can expect or not. Maybe, the solution is ok. What do you think? The solution using P4/P3 is very close to the exact solution too, that is why I'm trying to figure out why the case P2/P1 is not what I expect. Maybe it is related with the degree of the exact pressure.



The finite element method is guaranteed to converge, but this does not say anything about the accuracy on any specific (and in particular, on a coarse) mesh. All you know is that the error will decrease if you refine the mesh.
So if you observe the right convergence order, my guess would be that you implemented the method correctly. That you get better accuracy by using a higher-order method on the same mesh is not surprising. There is little else one can say, though you could of course compare what you get with one of the large finite element packages that all have example programs that solve the Stokes equations and that you can generally assume to be implemented correctly.

thanks Wolfgang for your comment. I would like to have the half of your experience.

Just to add to this, try interpolating the exact solution (since you know what it is) onto the finite element space. The coarsest mesh looks like it has only 4 points to a side and you've got a 6th degree polynomial. You can't expect to do any better than this on that mesh.
